# Do observers at rest at different positions in a gravitational field see the Universe expand at different rates

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, time

If we consider observers at rest outside a Schwarzschild black hole, the amount of proper time elapsed in terms of coordinate time is given by $\Delta\tau=\sqrt\frac{r-1}{r}\Delta t$ (where r is measured in units of Schwarzschild radius).  Does this mean that an observer at rest closer to the black hole will effectively see the Universe expand more quickly than an observer farther away?  I assume the answer is yes because if we imagine a hypothetical Universe that has a finite past/future, then two observers born at the beginning of the Universe who live in different gravitational potentials will have different ages at the end of the Universe, but is that interpretation missing something?  Is it even a sensible question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.

The time between events within a gravitational field in the Schwarzschild metric is
$$ \Delta \tau = \Delta t \left( 1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right)^{1/2},$$
where $\Delta t$ is the time between events seen by an observer at infinity and $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius.

If $\Delta t$ was (for example) the timescale for the universe to double in size, then the proper time for this to occur according to an observer deep within the gravitational field would be smaller.

Such corrections (on a smaller scale) are routinely made between clocks on Earth and on GPS satellites in order for the timing to be accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I've corrected the formula in the question.